# DXpopup position offset top relative to a variable

Tags: angular, devextreme

I'm trying to programmatically create a `dx-popup` in Angular4 with a custom offset from the top. Here's my code:

```
<dx-popup
    [position]= "{ my: 'left top', at: 'left top', offset: '0 100'}"
    [showTitle]="false"
    [dragEnabled]="false"
    [shading]="true"
    [height]="60"
    [shadingColor]= "'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'"
    [closeOnOutsideClick]="true"
    (onHidden)="closeMe()"
    [width] ="171"
    [(visible)]="isAlive">

</dx-popup>
```

This is working fine. The next step is to make the `position > offset` be setted from an `@Input()`. The variable is called `offsetY`. I've tried simply putting the var instead of the 100 like this:

`[position]= "{ my: 'left top', at: 'left top', offset: '0 offsetY'}"`

but the popup stick at 0 0 even tho `offsetY = 150`. Looking in the doc & forum of DevExtreme I couldn't find anything relevant about it.

Someone has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put offsetY variable inside a string. It wont be recognized. Try creating a string offsetY. So to achieve your functionality:-

```
[position]= "{ my: 'left top', at: 'left top', offset: offsetY}"
```

And in your component create a string,

```
offsetY: string = "0 150";
```

You can manipulate this string further for dynamic changes.

Comment: Thank you. Also if someone need to update all the position, the way I use is:  `this.popupPosition = { my: 'right top', at: 'right top', offset: '0 94'};`
     and then `this.popupComponent.instance.repaint();`